# Uniqueness of a json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

My app is receiving *payload* and I want to make sure it's recorded only once.
How can I create a uniqueness?

If the same publication is sent twice it shouldn't be saved.

**payload example**

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "publication",
    "attributes": {
      "advert": {
        "title": Super cat",
        "description": "Some dummy text",
        "customer": {
          "name": "Mozart"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: either hash the payload and compare it to already processed payload hashes or give each payload an `id` field which you then can compare.

Comment: Actually if the same publication is sent twice it makes a difference id..

Comment: that depends on the sender and how the sender generates ids - if a sender sends two events you should react to two events if the ids differ regardless of the entire payload.

Comment: Yes if the sender sends two different events I create both... but if he send duplicated publication, I keep one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found what expected

```
 validates :customer, uniqueness: {scope: :title}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure your payload is unique and only saved once, then you need to assign a field in your model to be unique. From the JSON example you provide, and stating that the same publication shouldn't be saved twice, one option is to make the title unique.

Your question is tagged Ruby on Rails, so you could use the following in your model to enforce this:

```
validates :title, uniqueness: true
```

Unless you are provided with an ID (as mentioned in the comments) or some other independently unique identifier, you need to pick a field returned in the payload to check against.

Comment: Yeah that's Ruby on rails :)
I though of `validates :title, uniqueness: true` but maybe another sender could publish an ad with the same title...
Actually I did it with `validates :description, uniqueness: true` but I was not sure if it was a good practice...
Was expecting for suggestion :) So It seems I was quite on the good way !